# Change label in webpage using jscriptexecutor of selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

We have an AUT a web application which is in Japanese. We are trying to follow below approach (not sure if it is correct) to get the Japanese label text into English.

**Approach (using Selenium):**

- Open web page.
- Get labels as we crawl web page.
- Send each label to an API (Japanese dictionary) to get it
  translated in English.
- Set back the translated English word to label using java script
  executor.

I have managed to get translated English word for the same Japanese label. However, I am stuck for setting it back on web page.
Below is the piece of code in selenium that tries to achieve the same.

```js
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("window.onload=function()document.getElementById('expiry').textContent='Expiration Date';}");
```

Here  there are no error messages in eclipse console but at same time I am not able to see the English text.

**HTML**

```HTML
    <html>
    <body>
    <table class="imui-form" style="width:1050px;">
    <div class="imui-chapter-title" style="width:1050px;">
    <h2>取引先情報</h2>
    </div>
    <tr>
    <th style="width:80px;" >
    <label id="expiry">有効期限</label>
    </th>
    <td style="width:220px;">
    <input type="text" placeholder="" value="2016/08/09"  name="fromdate" id="fromdate" maxlength="" style="width:100px; height:15px;">
    <img src="./imart/images/calendar_btn.png" />
    
    &nbsp;～&nbsp;
    <input type="text" placeholder="" value=""  name="todate" id="todate" maxlength="" style="width:100px; height:15px;">
    <img src="./imart/images/calendar_btn.png" />
    </td>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

With this, I have 2 queries:

1. Can anyone guide me if my approach is worth a try or if there is any
   better approach.
2. How should I make above java script work via selenium.